# ValueError: invalid \x escape for \x{ffff} in String

Tags: python, regex

I'm using [@diegoperini's regex from this site](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex):

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

I'm getting:

```
ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

For a part of the regex where there's a \x{some hex number} in a few places.

Is there a way to make this work? I've tried `\\x` and `\xffff`, neither seem to work.

Edit: Python port is in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294). Search for "adamrofer". It has exactly the solution proposed by jwodder.

Comment: I think you should remove the curly braces. So `\x{ffff} -> \xffff`

Comment: See my question, I tried this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As detailed here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), `\xFF` in Python only works when followed by exactly two hex digits without braces.  If you have four hex digits, you have to use `\u` instead: `\uFFFF` — and in the rare case where you have eight hex digits, that's `\U`: `\UFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: This fixes what I asked for. However, the regex doesn't seem to do anything (i.e. match any urls). I know that the html document I have contains URLs (I can copy and paste them into Chrome and get images).